# fingerprint door locks with notification

Tags: camera

I have no experience hacking electronics. I only am comfortable with software, so please forgive me if my question sounds very amateur.

The problem I am trying to solve is having a camera in the bathroom of my house turn on only when my brother is inside. I have an autistic brother who sneakily likes to throw stuff down the toilet when we're not looking. If I can catch him and show that we are recording him doing that, I think I can get him to stop. But of course, no one else in my family is ok with being recorded in the bathroom.

Attempting to use a webcam to real-time track the person in the bathroom and determine who's in it is very difficult to do since it is generally difficult to recognize a face unless it's a frontal view. Instead, ideally I would like to have installed fingerprint door locks on all the bathrooms. Upon detecting that my brother is entering, it can notify my server which can activate the camera.

I doubt that there is anything in the market which directly meets my needs, and I wonder about how feasible this is to do. My entire family would really really appreciate any advice!

Comment: I've come to think that combining motion detection and RFID for my family members to deactivate the camera might work. But this signal needs to be communicated wirelessly to my server, since my computer is obviously not in my bathroom. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could have a camera that everyone knows about exept your brother, so that they can cover it or turn it off when they are in the bathroom and uncover it/turn it on when they leave. Sorry for the low-tech suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it isn't that easy. He will also know how to cover it of course! And the purpose is to show him recordings of himself so that he realizes that we're recording him in the act. He is smart enough to find out where the camera is and cover it, so my plan was to mount it in the top corner of the bathroom where no one can reach.

Answer (score 2):

You probably only need to catch him once.  Why not have the camer manually triggered when someone notices your brother is in the bathroom?  I don't see why the system needs to be completely 100% efficient (catches him every time) and automated.  After all, right now it's 0% effecient.

I also like Com4's idea.  Let it run whenever anyone is in there (light is on, motion detector, whatever) and everyone except your brother knows to cover the camera with a towell, lens cap, etc.  They just have to remember to undo that when they leave.  Again, I don't see the big deal if the system misses some of the time.

How about not keeping small things that can be flushed down the toilet within easy reach in the bathroom?

Comment: It's not enough to catch him once. He doesn't work that way. I need to give him the impression that he will be caught every time he does it. Furthermore, it is not just flushing down the toilet that is the problem. He does all sorts of other things like wasting soap, wasting toilet paper, etc.

Comment: @bhh1988: What you say is not self-consistant.  He only has to *think* you are always watching.  That is different from actually catching him all the time.  Right now you're not catching him at all.  I would start with a simple low tech solution that catches him a few times.  You can always get more complicated if that doesn't work, but most likely it will do exactly what you want, which again is to have him *think* you are always watching.